# github action git diff could not access current sha error

Tags: github-actions

```
name: If files in folder_path were changed

on:
  push:

jobs:
  if-file-changed:
    name: Check if files changed
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Get files changed on push
        run: |
          echo ${{ github.sha }} - commit sha that triggered this workflow
          echo ${{ github.event.before }} - previous sha
          git --no-pager diff --name-only ${{ github.sha }} ${{ github.event.before }}
```

I get error - `error: Could not access 'oaisjdoiasjdoaijsd12319023'`
I am trying to get diff between 2 commit SHA's

The same command works fine when I run from local machine :

```
git --no-pager diff --name-only aosdiasodi oaisdoaisjd
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

order of sha's in question is wrong . correct order is -

```
git --no-pager diff --name-only ${{ github.event.before }} ${{ github.sha }}
```

But this wont work if you force push a commit because in that case the previous commit was overwritten hence rendered invalid.

Refer to [gha-files-changed](https://github.com/aseem-hegshetye/gha-files-changed) Github repo that implements this functionality

Answer (score 0):

I think you should clone  the repo bifore exec some local `git` command, so try this:

```
steps:
  - name: Checkout code
    uses: actions/checkout@v3
  - name: Get files changed on push
    run: |
      echo ${{ github.sha }} - commit sha that triggered this workflow
      echo ${{ github.event.before }} - previous sha
      git --no-pager diff --name-only ${{ github.sha }} ${{ github.event.before }}
```

See https://github.com/actions/checkout

Comment: Getting same error - `fatal: bad object 7be13398u2i3u2ui3`